# Highlighting cells underneath a header that spans 2 cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 2 tables: Table X and Table Y. I have a mouseover and mouseout handlers for Table X, which highlights related cells.

For Table Y, how can I **highlight the cells underneath a header that has a colspan of 2 or greater?**

```
- If header highlighted - highlight cells underneath it
- If row highlighted - highlight cells within that row
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RF7U3/10/

My attempts are in lower versions of the above fiddle (i.e.: http://jsfiddle.net/RF7U3/5/)

HTML:

```
Table X
<table id="table-x">
    <tr>
        <td class="b">Col A</td>
        <td class="b">Col B</td>
        <td class="b">Col C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="a">
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="a">
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
    </tr>
</table>

Table Y
<table id="table-y">
    <tr>
        <td class="b">Col A</td>
        <td class="b">Col B</td>
        <td class="b">Col C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="a">
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="a">
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
#table-x td {
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function highlight(selector, color) {
    $(selector).css('border-color', color);   
}

$('#table-x td.b').mouseover(function() {
   var columnIndex = $(this).index() + 1;
   var columnCells = $('#table-x td:nth-child(' + columnIndex + ')');
   highlight(columnCells, 'red'); 
}).mouseout(function() {
   var columnIndex = $(this).index() + 1;
   var columnCells = $('#table-x td:nth-child(' + columnIndex + ')');
   highlight(columnCells, 'inherit');  
});

$('#table-x tr.a').mouseover(function() {
    highlight($(this).find('td'), 'red');
}).mouseout(function() {
    highlight($(this).find('td'), 'inherit');
});
```

Comment: +1: Cool. I just answered this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24663018/how-do-i-select-rows-that-correspond-to-a-rowspan/24663137#24663137 so was in the mood for more of the same :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made quite a few alterations so that the events and changes are all relative to the cells hovered over. I also extracted the common code for mouse in & out as that became quite large:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/RF7U3/21/

```
function highlight(selector, color) {
    $(selector).css('border-color', color);
}

// Lightup the columns associated with this column
function lightup($th, color) {
    var $table = $th.closest('table');
    var columnIndex = $th.index();

    // Add up all the colspans from all columns to just before the one clicked (to find the correct start column below it)
    // Get the current colspan if any to determine the last column to include in the scan
    var colspan = ~~$th.attr('colspan') || 1;
    var $header = $table.find('tr:first').children().slice(0, columnIndex);
    var index = 0;
    $header.each(function (i) {
        index += ~~$(this).attr('colspan') || 1;
    });
    while (colspan > 0) {
        var columnCells = $table.find('tr').slice(1).find('td:nth-child(' + (index + colspan) + ')');
        highlight(columnCells, color);
        highlight($th, color);
        colspan--;
    }
}

$('table td.b').mouseover(function () {
    lightup($(this), 'red');
}).mouseout(function () {
    lightup($(this), 'inherit');
});

$('table tr.a').mouseover(function () {
    highlight($(this).find('td'), 'red');
}).mouseout(function () {
    highlight($(this).find('td'), 'inherit');
});
```

**Notes:**

- `~~` is a shortcut to convert a string value to an integer.
- `|| 0` converts an indefined value to 0.

Comment: Hi Aussie! Thanks for your interest on this. I found an issue with your code when there's succeeding headers after the spanning header. See http://jsfiddle.net/RF7U3/13/

Comment: Fair enough. Horrible example. Will try and adjust to cater for such things :) (basically nth-child is not a good enough solution)

Comment: Sorted. What a nightmare of +/- 1's. Phew. :) Obviously you will want to remove all the console.logs :)